# MySQL table not updating with ON DUPLICATE

Tags: mysql, sql, upsert

I'm using this query to select from joined tables, insert if new and update if duplicate:

```
Insert into test.ambition_test(ExtID, Extension, 
Total_Talk_Time_seconds,Total_Talk_Time_minutes,Total_Outbound, 
 Total_Inbound, Missed_Calls, Total_Calls, Time_of_report )  
SELECT 
RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID as ExtID
 , c.extension as Extension
, sum(Duration) as Total_Talk_Time_seconds
, round(sum(Duration) / 60,2) as Total_Talk_Time_minutes
, sum(if(LEGTYPE1 = 1,1,0)) as Total_Outbound
, sum(if(LEGTYPE1 = 2,1,0)) as Total_Inbound
, sum(if(Answered = 1,0,1)) as Missed_Calls
, count(DISTINCT b.NOTABLECALLID) as Total_Calls
, NOW()
FROM cdrdb.session a
JOIN cdrdb.callsummary b
ON a.NOTABLECALLID = b.NOTABLECALLID
 join cdrdb.mxuser c
  ON a.RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID = c.EXTENSIONID
  -- WHERE b.ts > (now() - interval 15 minute)
   WHERE b.ts >= curdate()
GROUP BY a.RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID
ORDER BY Total_Talk_Time_minutes DESC
ON duplicate key update Total_Talk_Time_seconds = Total_Talk_Time_seconds, 
Total_Talk_Time_minutes = Total_Talk_Time_minutes, Total_Outbound = 
Total_Outbound, Total_Inbound = Total_Inbound
  , Missed_calls = Missed_Calls, Total_Calls = Total_Calls, Time_of_report = 
Time_of_report;
```

I've been running it a few times today and each time it seems to add a few new records, but it doesn't seem to be updating any earlier records even though it should.

One possibility here is that I want this to treat the 'Extension' field, or perhaps even that coupled with 'ExtID', as the duplicate. ID is my primary key field in the test.ambition_test table and it auto increments, but I want this to update based on extension if they are already in the table, not just insert the new ones.

If I truncate the table and run the initial query again, it will do the initial insert and the values are much higher than the previous queries, which is correct. But then If I run the query over the next few hours, it only adds new extension records but no updates at all.

I altered my table in MySQL workbench and made 'ExtID' and 'Extension' Not NUll and Unique Index but I don't know if I should do anything else. Is there a reason this seems to not be updating existing records?

Comment: The correct syntax to update a column with the new value is `ON duplicate key update Total_Talk_Time_seconds = values(Total_Talk_Time_seconds), ...,`. You are currently "updating" each column with the current value, not the new value (which means you are not updating at all).

Comment: Oh no wonder. Thank you for that, I've never used this statement so the syntax I've found was for explicit values only. So I would do:
``` Total_Talk_Time_seconds = values(Total_Talk_Time_seconds), Total_Talk_Time_minutes = values(Total_Talk_Time_minutes),  ``` etc.

Comment: Ah, that worked perfectly. Thanks so much!